# How do I get days between dates

Tags: python, timedelta

I need to remove files that are older than 14 days from a directory that stores our backups. I can get the time of an individual file by using something like this:

```
start = (os.path.getmtime(join(dirpath, name))/3600*24)
```

But I'm getting confused with how I use timedelta to find the difference between this and the current date.

I'd like to use something like this:

```
d = (datetime.timedelta(time.now() - os.path.getmtime(join(dirpath, dirname))
```

but I'm just not getting it.  I'm on my own here, and I'd love some help.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
if time.time() - os.path.getmtime(filename) > 14 * 24 * 3600:
  print 'the file is older than 14 days'
```

Comment: Tried and good, thank you very much.  Added the appropriate number of brackets and it might just do the trick for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

a `timedelta` is the result of subtracting a `datetime` from another `datetime`. in this example i show that my `/bin/bash` is 1168 days and some older than my `/dev/null`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import os.path
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime("/dev/null"))
datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 24, 18, 58, 28, 504962)
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime("/bin/bash"))
datetime.datetime(2008, 5, 12, 15, 2, 42)
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime("/dev/null"))-datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime("/bin/bash"))
datetime.timedelta(1168, 14146, 504962)
>>> d = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime("/dev/null"))-datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime("/bin/bash"))
>>> d.days
1168
```

Answer (score 0):

```
datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=14)
```

Something like that?

Answer (score 0):

aix has a perfectly good answer using the `time` module.  Here's an answer that uses `datetime`.

```
from datetime import *
maxdays = timedelta(14)
mtime =datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(filename))
if mtime - datetime.now() > maxdays:
    print filename, 'older than 14 days'
```